# metric variations at a point

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Consider a Riemannian manifold $M$, and the following objects: 
 1. Metric variations in a small neighborhood of a point $p$.
 2. Diffeomorphisms in a small neighborhood of a point $p$.

Where can I read about these objects (what are these called)? Is there is a sense in which we can mod out by diffeomorphisms and look at (1)/(2)?

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. What do you want to know about these beyond the definitions? Yes, you can form the quotient of the space of metrics by the group of diffeomorphisms.